# IIS always search file in the wrong directory

Tags: iis

On my PC (Windows 10) I wrote a new website (VB windows forms, .aspx files).
If I run the site from inside Visual Studio 2019, all OK, it starts and run correctly.
Now I need to have this site always "ON", I installed IIS, configured a "new website", name, directory and so on. I configured the new website in IIS to the directory where I develop, not in wwwroot.

Nothing works: I always have a 404 error.
To simplyfy everything I wrote a simple .HTML file, "prova.html", I placed it in the real website directory, and I tested it with Firefox: http://127.0.0.1/test.html.
Still 404:

```
URL requested      http://127.0.0.1:80/prova.html
Physical path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prova.html
```

It seems that IIS ALWAYS searches the file in the wrong path, but I configured the correct directory where the file is.

Of course if I place my test file in "inetpub\wwwroot ..." IIS finds and opens the file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following steps to deploy the project in IIS:

Right click on your project and select publish:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then add the site in IIS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial: this way "something" happens. 
Now if I type "http://localhost/login.aspx" in Firefox, the browser finds and loads the correct page. 
But happens something strange: it seems that somethins is missing, maybe the interaction between HTML and VB. I see code, not "TextBox" where I can type username and password. In the browser I see things like "<%: Title %>."

Comment: I think this may be a problem with your code.

Comment: Of course it can be, but if is it, i don't understand a) what problem b) why from inside Visual Studio everything works as expected

Comment: You can check whether the page source code comparison is different from your code in the browser.I think this should not be an IIS problem, it is probably a problem with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ... installing IIS I didn't install the .NET part ... I feel very stupid.